# How do you repeat a list within a list comprehension?

Tags: list, list-comprehension

I'm working on my list comprehension skills, looking for exercises to sharpen my understanding. But I've reached one that I can't seem to get around. Let's say I want a list of all possible lists containing 3 random digits in range(1,3), wherein each list's sum does not amount to 3.

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0] ...]
```

Clearly, I need to do this with nested list comprehensions. But I'm not really sure how to go about it. As far as I know, I can't assign a list to a variable within the list comprehension. But I need that variable to refer to the output:

```
list7 = [[randint(0,2) for x in range(3)] for y if sum(y) != 3]
```

This gives me a syntax error. I've tried assigning the inner list to a variable first, and that doesn't seem to work, either:

```
y = [randint(0,2) for x in range(3)]
list7 = [y for y if sum(y) != 3]
```

What perplexes me, though, is that "y" gives no error at all here. It behaves as I expect even though randint isn't assigned to "x". Apparently there's something I don't understand here. So, here is my question: How can I repeat a nested list in list comprehension if I can't assign it to a variable within the comprehension? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try working from the inside out to make sure you understand your data structures and their content. [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) are described well in the python docs including an example very close to yours. Also, solving your own syntax problems will teach you more than getting an answer here.

Comment: I fail to see the point of stack overflow if the only help I can receive for my understanding is "go read the documentation and try to solve your own problem", Peter. I've been doing just that, and I am having trouble. That's why I've come here.

Comment: The outer list comprehension is not a list comprehension in `list7` because there is nothing being iterated over. I.e. an `in foo` clause.

Comment: @PleasantNightmares sorry you feel that way. as @dpwrussel points out, there's no `in` in your second list comprehension. Some things just take a lot of plarying around, rechecking, etc. You'll get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out in my comment, a problem with your solution is that the outer list comprehension has no iterable. So how would it know how many results to produce, or when to stop producing results?

There is also a problem with your `if` clause. In your `if` you do `sum(y)` which I assume was intended to mean, "do a sum of the result of `[randint(0,2) for x in range(3)]`". This is backwards because the `if` is executed first. Also, y is the loop variable for the current item in the iterator and not the result of the list comprehension for that item.

Another problem with your solution is that you are using `randint`. So you might produce some combinations many times and others not at all. This is somewhat besides the point.

I think probably you were looking to turn something like this into a list comprehension.

```
results = []
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            if i + j + k != 3:
                results.append([i, j, k])
```

Which is totally doable, but the answer isn't nested list comprehensions because that is for when you need to generate lists of lists and in this case, only your outer list needs a comprehensions, your inner lists is just 3 digits in a container. It could just as easily have been a tuple.

It's best to think about this from the perspective of what you want to end up with, a list of lists. That means you need something which generates a list, which contains other lists.

So you want to generate those 3 digits, check if they add up to 3 and if not, they are one of the items that are added to your results as a list. You can take advantage of the fact that list comprehensions in python support multiple iterators, to achieve the same thing as the nested for loops.

```
results = [
    [i, j, k] 
    for i in range(3) for j in range(3) for k in range(3)
    if i + j + k != 3
]
```

See the official docs for a lot more useful examples: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

---

Edit:

It occurred to me that what you were trying to do was this:

```
results = [
    item for item in [
        [i, j, k] 
        for i in range(3) for j in range(3) for k in range(3)
    ]
    if sum(item) != 3
]
```

Which looks a bit more like your code. This is equivalent in terms of results, but can be a lot less performant (both in terms of process and memory) because in this example, you construct all the `[i, j, k]` possibilities into a list, and then filter them down to the ones that don't add up to 3. It's better to never have constructed those lists at all. for this trivial example it makes little difference, but if `[x, y, z]` was expensive to construct or each item used non-trivial amounts of memory, it could matter.

Comment: or just `[t for t in [(x, y, z) for x in range(3) for y in range(3) for z in range(3)] if sum(t) != 3]`  to overuse list comprehension.

Comment: That's exactly the same as my alternate solution, just written in one line and using a tuple for the container!